# Ubuntu Studio and KDE

Tags: kde, ubuntu-studio

I've recently installed Ubuntu Studio, but I prefer the KDE interface to the Gnome/Ubuntu interface.  Is there a way to convert Studio to KDE?  Is this a good idea?  And if it is, will I still have problems in keeping my system up-to-date?

Comment: Just a pointer, Ubuntu Studio does not come with GNOME by default, it has Xfce.

Comment: @pomsky This is one of the reasons we repurposed Ubuntu Studio Installer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of doing this is by installing Kubuntu then installing [Ubuntu Studio Installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioInstaller) to get the special "Ubuntu Studio" treatment for your system. We made it just for this purpose.